# In Python, what is the difference between "*largs" and "*args" or "*kwargs"?

Tags: python

In Python, what is the difference between "*largs" and "*args" or "*kwargs" as an argument?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: nothing if they all start by one `*`. `kwargs` is generally used for the keywords so it's often `**kwargs`

Comment: `*kwargs` is especially useful if you want to lose friends and alienate people.

Comment: The name after the `*` is just the name of the parameter that will contain a list of all of the extra arguments. I'm not sure why someone would call it `largs` instead of `args`, and `kwargs` is downright misleading, but ultimately you can call it whatever you want. (In the same way you can define a method with `lself` or `this` or `rockmeamadeus` as the first argument instead of `self` if you really want to, but you shouldn't.)

Comment: [*largs](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Larg_(Captain))?